# Transforming dataframe in 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a python dataframe (`dataLabel`) like this:

```
Index |      Name        |  Label
  0   |   img0001.jpg    |    0
  1   |   img0002.jpg    |    3
  2   |   img0005.jpg    |    7
```

I want to create 2 dictionaries from the previous dataframe. The first contains all the image names and the second all the labels.

```
1st dictionary(Name):  # All entries in dataframe belong to the key `train`
{'train': ['img0001.jpg', 'img0002.jpg', 'img0005.jpg']}  

2nd dictionary(labels):
{'img0001.jpg': 0, 'img0002.jpg': 3, 'img0005.jpg': 7}
```

I tried transforming the dataframe into a dictionary using the function `to_dict()` and manipulate the resulting dict.

```
dictionaryObject = dataLabel.to_dict()   

Name={"train":dictionaryObject["image"][:]}
```

However, the following error occurs: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`.

I have no idea how to do the `labels` dictionary, is there a simple way or function to do it? Regarding the `Name` dictionary how can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first dictionary, just use `tolist` on the column:

```
dict1 = {"train": df["Name"].tolist()}
```

For the second, `zip` two columns together:

```
dict2 = dict(zip(df["Name"], df["Label"]))
```